# Lambda implicit convert trouble?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

Having trouble with this expression in my controller. I'm working on an MVC 4 project, and I have some audit records coming back, along with a list of applications that has been filtered per user, and per what apps are in their audit history. I'm adding filtering to the audit log by using a drop down list, that uses an ajax call to a method that re-runs the audit log with the appid of the selected item in the dropdown list against the audit records, and returns only audit records that contain that matching appid. Having a problem with the expression to get it to filter though. Here is what I have right now:

The method I'm using to accomplish this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetRows(String username, int page, int? appId)
    {

        User user = UserManager.GetUser(username);
        var filteredApps = UserManager.GetUserAppListFromAuditRecord(user);
        List<ApplicationListView> appList = filteredApps.Select(Mapper.DynamicMap<ApplicationListView>).ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> appsList = appList.Select(appItem => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = appItem.Name,
            Value = appItem.ID.ToString()
        }).ToList();
        ViewData["UserAppList"] = appsList;
        SearchInfo searchInfo = new SearchInfo { UserName = username };
        var auditRecord = _userHelper.GetAuditInfo(searchInfo, page);
        **var filteredRows = auditRecord.AuditRecords.Where(a => a.ApplicationID = appList.Select(t => t.ID).ToList();**
        return PartialView(auditRecord);

    }
```

Best to inform you that the filtering of the applist per user is done on the backend when the call to the db is made. that's why it's being mapped to the viewmodel, and then stuffed into a selectlist. The part i'm having trouble with is the "filteredRows" variable. I'm trying to compare the auditrecords with the appid from the select list and return filtered results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it right and you need `a.ApplicationID` to be among `appList` you can use `Any` for this:

```
var filteredRows = auditRecord.AuditRecords.Where(a => appList.Any(t => t.ID == a.ApplicationID)).ToList();
```

Comment: I didn't even think about using "Any", thank you for that. Will mark this as correct as soon as SO lets me. Once again, thank you!